# How to create correctly the "raw" folder(/res/raw) in order to play audio file puted in it

Tags: android, eclipse, audio-streaming

When I create a new project the "raw" folder does not appear automaticaly and I have to do it manually. The problem is that after creation of this folder and when I already copied the audio file in it I can't define it, as it's happens  in tutorials, using R.raw.audio.mp3(also in R.java there is no declaration about raw folder). The line of code with error is 
MediaPlayer playMyMusic = new MediaPlayer().create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.Song);
and the error apears at raw (error: "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field")
Must to note that I'm new in android development and sorry for bad English.

Comment: `yourpackage.R.raw` should be accessible from your application without an issue. Clean and rebuild. `yourapp/res/raw` is the correct path. Also double-check that `R` is actually yours and not from another package.

Comment: res/raw has to be added manually, because not all projects use it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "res" folder New Directory, name "raw"